# What is the average distance from a point on a circle to its circumference?

Tags: geometry

An example would be the following: imagine a circle with a diameter of 1 on a grid. Two points on this circle are 0,0 and 1,0. Two other points would be 0.5,0.5 and 0.5,-0.5). We are ignoring negative y values on this grid, the grid is just for illustration. The average distance from 0,0 of the first 2 points is (1+0)/2=0.5. The average of the 4 points is 0.6 = (1+0+2*sqrt(2*0.5^2))/4. What is the average distance from 0,0 for the set of all points on the circle?

Comment: What have you tried?  You need to integrate over the circle to get the answer.